# Alchemy WebSocketClient

Tags: c#, java, websocket

I am reviewing some WebSocket implementations both server and client.  Should an Alchemy WebSocketClient be able to connect to ws://echo.websocket.org?

```
WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient("ws://echo.websocket.org") { Origin = "localhost", OnReceive = OnClientReceive };
        client.Connect();
        client.Send("This is a test.");
        client.Disconnect();
```

I receive this error in Visual Studio : ***Input string was not in a correct format.***  Seems to be related to the URI.  But I can connect to that UIR using my Java/Jetty client.

I also have a problem connecting an Alchemy client to an Java Jetty implementation using.  I receive an error on the server side : 
***2013-11-16 01:37:14.844:WARN:oejh.HttpParser:qtp495053715-27: badMessage: 400 for HttpChannelOverHttp@707481f3{r=45279,a=IDLE,uri=-}***

If I write a WebSocketServer using Alchemy, the WebSocketClient works as advertised using an address such as "ws://localhost:9090/echo".

Connecting to an Alchemy Server using a Java/Jetty client works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change `ws://echo.websocket.org` to `ws://echo.websocket.org/`, it should work without any further hassles.